# Change JDK version for jdeveloper 11g(11.2) in ubuntu

Tags: java-7, jdeveloper

I am working on a project in `jdeveloper` where it needs to be built in `JDK-7`. But when I go to project properties it shows `jdk-6` which is preinstalled with weblogic. when compiling project, it also says it is jdk-6. How can I change this?
There is an option though from project properties to change jdk, but I am not sure as it is using weblogic's default jdk and its purpose and hence being very imported project I don't want to change without knowing anything for sure.
Btw, my `JAVA_HOME` is set to `jdk-7`. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDeveloper uses its own settings, tends to ignore $JAVA_HOME.
And different versions use different JDK versions and are pretty much hardwired to them.

JDeveloper 11 is linked to JDK6, JDeveloper 12.1 is linked to JDK7, JDeveloper 12.2 is linked to JDK8.

These coincide with the supported versions of ADF and other Oracle specific frameworks as well. If you need to work with different versions of those, you need to have different versions of JDeveloper installed.

While you might be able to select a JDK to compile against that's older than the newest supported version for a release, compiling against a newer JDK is typically not supported in any IDE. It's been several years since I've used JDeveloper, but that was the case back then and the versions I used were 11 and 12 at the time.

Comment: thank you!
I was then exploring and got to know that too!
Btw, thanks

Comment: btw if anyone is stuck not being able to change Java Home after running JDeveloper 12c copied from another machine (where it asked you to choose JDK location on the first run) - try renaming the previously selected Java Home directory so that to force JDeveloper to ask you to choose the new Java Home location

Answer (score 1):

[Change JDK used by JDeveloper](http://markchensblog.blogspot.com/2014/06/change-jdk-used-by-jdeveloper.html)

The JDK configuration for JDeveloper is defined in the `jdev.conf` which located in your `Jdeveloper folder\jdeveloper\jdev\bin`.

Open the file and find the item SetJavaHome.  Change its value to your new JDK folder.

In the below example I switch JDK from JDK 7 to JDK 6 by commenting out JDK 7 and adding a new item for JDK 6.

```
#SetJavaHome C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_06
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
```

After saving the changes restart JDeveloper and it will use the new JDK set in jdev.conf.

You can check JDK used in JDeveloper from JDeveloper.
From JDeveloper goes to Help->About.  Then select the tab Properties and will find java.home properties now is set to the JDK specified in jdev.conf.